# How do I get Android Admob App Open Ads to show in 21.4.0?

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

I just upgraded from Admob 20.6.0 to 21.4.0 in an Android project. Up until the upgrade, Admob App Open ads were working as expected. In 21.4.0 I am getting an error in `showAdIfAvailable()`

> Type mismatch. Required: Activity Found: Activity?

On this line:

```
appOpenAd?.show(currentActivity)
```

Code correct suggests the following, **but the problem is this code never runs.**

```
currentActivity?.let { appOpenAd?.show(it) }
```

**Here's the full code for AppOpenManager:**

```
class AppOpenManager(private val myApplication: MainActivity) : DefaultLifecycleObserver, Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    private var appOpenAd: AppOpenAd? = null
    private var loadCallback: AppOpenAdLoadCallback? = null
    private var currentActivity : Activity? = null
    private var isShowingAd : Boolean = false
    private var loadTime:Long = 0

    /** Creates and returns ad request.  */
    private fun getAdRequest():AdRequest {
        return AdRequest.Builder().build()
    }
    /** Utility method that checks if ad exists and can be shown. */
    private fun isAdAvailable():Boolean {
        return appOpenAd != null && wasLoadTimeLessThan4HoursAgo()
    }



    /** Constructor  */
    init {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            this.myApplication.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this)
        }
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }


    /** Request an ad  */
    fun fetchAd() {

        if (isAdAvailable()) {
            // Have unused ad, no need to fetch another.
            return
        }
        loadCallback = object : AppOpenAdLoadCallback() {

            override fun onAdLoaded(ad: AppOpenAd) {
                this@AppOpenManager.appOpenAd = ad
                this@AppOpenManager.loadTime = (Date()).time
            }

            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(loadAdError: LoadAdError) {
                println("onAppOpenAdFailedToLoad $loadAdError")
            }

        }
        val request: AdRequest = getAdRequest()

        AppOpenAd.load(myApplication, StaticData.appOpenID, request, AppOpenAd.APP_OPEN_AD_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT, loadCallback as AppOpenAdLoadCallback)

    }


    override fun onStart(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        super.onStart(owner)
        showAdIfAvailable()
        println("onStart")
    }


    private fun showAdIfAvailable() {
        // Only show ad if there is not already an app open ad currently showing and an ad is available.
        if (!isShowingAd && isAdAvailable()){
            println("Will show ad.")
            val fullScreenContentCallback = object: FullScreenContentCallback() {
                override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                    // Set the reference to null so isAdAvailable() returns false.
                    this@AppOpenManager.appOpenAd = null
                    isShowingAd = false
                    fetchAd()
                }
                override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError: AdError) {}
                override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                    isShowingAd = true
                }
            }
            appOpenAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = fullScreenContentCallback
            appOpenAd?.show(currentActivity) // Type mismatch. Required: Activity Found: Activity?
        }
        else
        {
            println("Can not show ad... FETCH ONE INSTEAD!")
            fetchAd()
        }
    }


    /** Utility method to check if ad was loaded more than n hours ago. */
    private fun wasLoadTimeLessThan4HoursAgo():Boolean {
        val dateDifference = (Date()).time - this.loadTime
        val numMilliSecondsPerHour:Long = 3600000
        return (dateDifference < (numMilliSecondsPerHour * 4))
    }

    override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) {
        println("⚠️ onActivityPaused")
    }

    override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {
        println("⚠️ onActivityStarted")
        currentActivity = activity
    }

    override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) {
        println("⚠️ onActivityDestroyed")
        currentActivity = null
    }

    override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, outState: Bundle) {
        println("⚠️ onActivitySaveInstanceState")
    }

    override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity) {
        println("⚠️ onActivityStopped")
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        println("⚠️ onActivityCreated")
    }

    override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) {
        println("⚠️ onActivityResumed")
        currentActivity = activity
    }

}
```

**And in MainActivity:**

```
private var appOpenManager: AppOpenManager? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    //...
    appOpenManager = AppOpenManager(this)
}
```

**How do I get Android Admob App Open Ads to show in 21.4.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Type mismatch. Required: Activity Found: Activity?

this error came because they made a major change

> Added @NonNull annotations in every method that previously did not explicitly define nullability. -- in [21.0.0](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rel-notes#21.0.0)

---

> but the problem is this code never runs `currentActivity?.let { appOpenAd?.show(it) }`

That is a correct way to solve the above error. I'll assume here that `currentActivity` is null or `addOpenAd` is null so the `show(it)` function call doesn't happen. Without logcat it's hard to see the root cause is, but here are a few things to check. I think one of these will be the solution:

1. Ensure that `onAdFailedToLoad` doesn't get called by looking for the log line. This will make sure that `appOpenAd` is assigned.
2. Make sure you're testing on Q+, because only on those versions will your code work. On older versions `currentActivity` will never get assigned. Because the lifecycle callbacks from `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks` will not be registered.
3. It could be a timing issue too, you might need an additional code path to prepare for this case:

   - App starts and ad starts loading in the background
     (`appOpenAd = null, currentActivity = null`)
   - Activity is started and shown
     (`appOpenAd = null, currentActivity = !null`)
     `showAdIfAvailable` is called, but there's no ad yet
     BUG: it'll start loading another one!
   - Ad finishes loading
     (appOpenAd = !null, currentActivity = !null)
     BUG: nothing else is called from `onAdLoaded`

Comment: Rob, I think you're onto something here: "Because the lifecycle callbacks from registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks will not be registered." - onActivityStarted is not getting called, thus currentActivity remains null. I don't want to stray too far from the topic, but how can I get onActivityStarted called on Android < Q?

Comment: `class ComponentActivity implements LifeCycleOwner`, so what you get in `onStart` of `DefaultLifecycleObserver` **IS** the activity. As far as I know the `androidx-lifecycle` is the support library for `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks`, so you only need the observer, remove `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`, and override more of `DefaultLifecycleObserver`.